# Renaming API names in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to rename my column name in the API.

```php
$test_table = DB::table('test_table')->select('id','test_col')->paginate(10);

return $test_table;
```

I get returned this:

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "test_col": "Test one"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "test_col": "Test two"
        },
```

But what if I want to rename the test_col to name how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use \DB::raw():

```
 $test_table = DB::table('test_table')->select('id',DB::raw('test_col as col_alias'))->paginate(10);
        return $test_table;
```